# Good Example for ORACLE RAW(16) and Hibernate UUID generation

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

I'm having a problem setting up Hibernate to work with Oracle RAW(16) for UUID

Is there a perfect example on the web?

1) Expecting String but found RAW
2) not long

currently I am using String for UUID, and varchar(36) in oracle.

May I know how can I use RAW and UUID type to set up this UUID

Comment: How about just writing your own [usertype](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#types-custom-ut)? This isn't too difficult.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle,

```
myUUID RAW(16) PK
```

JPA / hibernate,

```
@Id
@Type(type = "uuid-binary")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "myGUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "myGUID", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "myUUID", length = 16, unique= true, nullable = false)
public UUID getMyUUID() {
    return uuid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DB: Oracle, 
It's super simply with Spring Data. Just create entity looking similar to this

```
@Entity
public class SimpleUUID {
    @Column(name = "MY_FIELD")
    private UUID myField;

    ...

    //getters and setters omitted for simplicity 
}
```

And of course you need to create this one on the db but this one is also pretty simple (with using LIQUIBASE for instance)

```
<createTable tableName="SIMPLE_UUID">
            <column name="MY_FIELD" type="RAW(16)"/>
 </createTable>
```